# Bootstrap modal pushes my jumbotron to left in chrome but not in edge?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried some of the ways in other questions given for bootstrap modal but I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 this shouldn't be the issue ,but I have no idea why this is happening every time I click on button my jumbotron shrinks !!Any help would be appreciated.

My html code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div id="post"></div>
   <div id="erase" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="erase()">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="border-radius:100%;width:80px;height:80px;padding:15px">
         <img src="/uploads/text.png" style="height:40px;width:40px" />
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

My javascript function:

```
function erase(){
  $('#post').empty();

  $('#post').html('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">'+'<div class="modal-dialog">'+'<div class="modal-content">'+
            '<div class="modal-header">'+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
            '<h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family:Pangolin">Post your text</h4>'+' </div>'+'<div class="modal-body">'+
            '<div class="media "><div class="media-left"> <form action="porthome_.php" method="post" id="usrform" >'+

          '<div class="form-group"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="font-size:13px" ></span> Write your post:</strong> <input form="usrform" id="textarea1" type="text" class="form-control" name="image" placeholder="Write something" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add the image link from any site,if in doubt check out our videos on how to upload images in post.">'+ 
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="text-right">'+
          '<button type="submit" id="sub"class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</form><div class="media-body"> <a href="#"><h5 class="media-heading" style="color:#3369e8"></h5></a>'+
           '</div>'+
           '</div>'+
           '</div>'+'<div class="modal-footer">'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+'</div>'+
            '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>');
        }
```

Comment: Where is ** jumbotron** class in your code??

Comment: my html code is inside the jumbotron

Comment: Is your code looks like https://jsfiddle.net/qc9dgefg/1/ ??

Comment: yup, but in jsfiddle it is not shifting,am I correct?

Comment: Yes, your code works perfectly fine in jsfiddle...

Comment: but its shifting man,believe me

Comment: Can post your entire code in an updated jsfiddle..... I need your entire code to encounter the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/qc9dgefg/2/

```js
 erase = function(){
  $('#post').empty();

  $('#post').html(
   `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family:Pangolin">Post your text</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left"> 
                <form action="porthome_.php" method="post" id="usrform" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="font-size:13px" ></span> 
                        Write your post:
                    </strong>
                    <input form="usrform" id="textarea1" type="text" class="form-control" name="image" placeholder="Write something" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add the image link from any site,if in doubt check out our videos on how to upload images in post."> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" id="sub"class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div class="media-body"> 
                  <a href="#"><h5 class="media-heading" style="color:#3369e8"></h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
     </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>`);
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="post"></div>
    <div id="erase" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="erase()">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="border-radius:100%;width:80px;height:80px;padding:15px">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height:40px;width:40px">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You were **missing** one of the **closing div tag**.

I have added the **closing div tag** along with that I also **formatted** the dynamic `HTML` in `JavaScript`.